# Android multi-timer which can be set to ring based on a list of successive number of days intervals (with optional start date and end date)

Tags: android, time-management

The stock Android Clock (Alarm/World Clock/Stopwatch/Timer/Desk clock) application lacks the following features:

1. Multi-timer (specify more than one timer, each having its own time interval and text, and each timer can be saved separately and be started/paused/restarted/deleted). This is very useful if for example you must cook, and time different things which may be cooking at the same time.
2. When you set an alarm, the stock application allows you to specify whether to repeat weekly. It also allows you to specify the days of the week it should ring (out of M,T,W,T,F,S,S). What I would like is a replacement for this where the latter option where, instead of specifying the days of the week where the alarm should sound, you specify the (a) the start date, and (b) a space-separated list of every how many days apart the timer should ring.
3. Each alarm, could also have an optional start date and end date. If none of these are specified, then the alarm becomes effective today, and will repeat forever.

As an example of this, I could have alarms:

---

Alarm Name: Wake Up
Alarm Time: 7:00
Repeat Type: Specify Days of the Week
Repeat Days: MTWTF
(this has already been implemented)

---

Alarm Name: Water Flowers
Alarm Time: 19:30
Repeat Type: Specify Day Interval
Start Day: today
Repeat Day Intervals: 3
(this has not implemented; the alarm will ring today at 19:30 and at the same time three, six, nine, twelve, fifteen, etc... days from now).

---

Alarm Name: Take Medicine X
Alarm Time: 15:30
Repeat Type: Specify Day Interval
Start Day: tomorrow
Repeat Day Intervals: 3, 5
(this has not implemented; the alarm will ring tomorrow at 15:30, and then at the same time four, nine, twelve, seventeen, twenty, twentyfive... etc... days from now (because the cycle which in this case consists of two repeat day intervals, will cycle after reaching the end).

three, six, nine, twelve, fifteen, etc... days from now).

---

If no such application exists, then can someone please tell me where to download the source code for the stock Clock Android application so that I may enhance it    so that such programmable behaviors may be included?

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using [Tasker](http://goo.gl/7DN3cv)

Comment: and what about [Multi Timer StopWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jee.timer&hl=en)