# Android alarm app with repeating alarms

Tags: android, alarm-clock

I'm looking for an Android alarm app that allows you to have repeating/recurring alarms.

For example, I might want to have repeating alarms at 2pm every third Tuesday.

I looked at [Multi Timer StopWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jee.timer&hl=en), as recommended in the comments on [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18013/71077), but this only allowed for repeating every Tuesday, and not once every third Tuesday.

I know Google Calendar allows for having an event every Tuesday (for example), but does not provide any customization of the notification for the event (other than how long before the event the notification is displayed). I want to be able to choose a sound or vibration pattern for the repeating alarm.

Both free and paid suggestions are acceptable.

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify the difference between Free & Unpaid please?

Comment: @SteveBarnes "unpaid" was a typo, please see my updated question.